# Gram-Charlier expansion, option price, higher derivative and integration by parts

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, derivatives

I am currently reading a finance paper of Backus et al. (2004), called 'Accounting for biases in Black-Scholes'. To explain an abnormality called 'volatility smirk' that can be found in option prices, the authors use a Gram-charlier expansion of normal density whose function is defined as

$$
f(w)=\left(1-\frac{\gamma_{1}}{3!}D^{3}+\frac{\gamma_{2}}{4!}D^{4}\right)\phi(w),
$$
where $\gamma_{1}$ is skewness of the density, $\gamma_{2}$ is kurtosis of the density, $\phi(w)=(2\pi)^{1/2}\exp(-w^{2}/2)$ and $w$ stands for the one-period log-return $\log S_{t+1}-\log S_{t}$. As you may already know, a price of European call option $C(S(t),K,t,\tau)$ with underlying price $S(t)$, stirke price $K$, current time $t$ and time to maturity $\tau$ can be defined as

$$
C(S,K,\tau)=e^{-r\tau}E(S(t+\tau)-K)^{+} \\
= e^{-r\tau}\int_{\log(K/S(t))}^{\infty}(S(t)e^{w}-K)p(w)dw,
$$
where $p$ is the probability density function for the underlying asset price which is random. This paper says that given the distribution $f$ above, the integral part of call price equation becomes
$$
\int_{\log(K/S(t))}^{\infty}(S(t)e^{w}-K)f(w)dw=\int_{w^{*}}^{\infty}(S(t)e^{\mu+\sigma w}-K)\phi(w)dw \\
-\frac{\gamma_{1}}{3!}\int_{w^{*}}^{\infty}(S(t)e^{\mu+\sigma w}-K)\phi^{'''}(w)dw \\
+\frac{\gamma_{2}}{4!}\int_{w^{*}}^{\infty}(S(t)e^{\mu+\sigma w}-K)\phi^{(4)}(w)dw \\
\equiv I_{1}-\frac{\gamma_{1}}{3!}I_{2}+\frac{\gamma_{1}}{4!}I_{3},
$$
where $w^{*}=\log(K/S_{t}-\mu)/\sigma$, $\mu$ is the expected rate of return, and $\sigma$ is the volatility of underlying asset price.

My question is about the derivation of $I_{3}$. In this paper, authors say that
$$
I_{3}=\sigma K\phi(w^{*})[(w^{*})^{2}-1+\sigma w^{*}+\sigma^{2}]+\sigma^{4}I_{1}+\sigma^{4}K\Phi(-w^{*}),
$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative density function for $\phi$. It is mentioned that repeated application of integration by parts and a property of derivatives of the normal density $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{x}\phi^{(n)}(x)=0$ are used for this derivation. Now I can derive all the other terms, but I still cannot find where the minus one in the middle comes from. I would be really appreciated if someone could tell me where it comes from. The original paper can be found at http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lwu/papers/bias.pdf. This question is related to the proof of proposition 1, which can be found on page 23 and 24.